# Download Unzip Upload clodinary

Tags: node.js, unzip, cloudinary

I am trying to download a ZIP file with request pipe it to [node-unzip](https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip) then pipe it to cloudinary.

```
var stream = cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream(function(result) {
  console.log(result)
});

request(file_url).pipe(unzip.Parse()).pipe(stream); //<-- This do not work!
ERROR: { error: { message: 'Empty file', http_code: 400 } }

fs.createReadStream('my_picture.jpg').pipe(stream); //<-- This works!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(You didn't mention, but I'm assuming your `request` var is an instance of [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request))*

First check that your zip is valid and contains what you expect it to:

(code taken from [node-unzip's readme](https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip#parse-zip-file-contents))

```
var unzip = require('unzip');
var request = require('request');
var fstream = require('fstream');
var writeStream = fstream.Writer('output/path');

request(file_url)
  .pipe(unzip.Parse())
  .pipe(writeStream);
```

Then, send a single entry from a zip (even if there is only one):

```
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
var unzip = require('unzip');
var request = require('request');
var stream = cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream(function(result) {
  console.log(result)
});
request(file_url)
  .pipe(unzip.Parse())
  .on('entry', function (entry) {
    var fileName = entry.path;
    var type = entry.type; // 'Directory' or 'File'
    var size = entry.size;
    if (fileName === "your_image.png") {
      entry.pipe(stream);
    } else {
      entry.autodrain();
    }
  });
```